# macOS - Photos app crash when tapping on a particular person

Tags: mac, macos, photos

In Photos app on my Mac, every time I click on Wife's People/Faces folder, it just immediately crashes. I've tried repairing my Photos library many times, but alas, the problem still exists. How do I resolve this issue? I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4.

Refer to the lines below from the error report:

```
Process:               Photos [87896]
Path:                  /Applications/Photos.app/Contents/MacOS/Photos
Identifier:            Photos
Version:               3.0 (3271.13.150)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Photos [87896]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-05-29 19:28:52.458 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.4 (17E202)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        42D2D57D-1D7D-F6FC-51EC-4B99808FDD23


Time Awake Since Boot: 290000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
*** error for object 0x7fad3d2f9600: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00007fff6cf39b6e __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff6d104080 pthread_kill + 333
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff6ce951ae abort + 127
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib        0x00007fff6cf9ead4 szone_error + 596
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib        0x00007fff6cfa00eb small_free_list_remove_ptr_no_clear + 790
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib        0x00007fff6cfa0434 free_small + 814
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff44ac95fd -[__NSSetM dealloc] + 45
7   libobjc.A.dylib               0x00007fff6c1c5087 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 817
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff44af18cc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff44ad42a3 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 275
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff44ad4068 __CFRunLoopRun + 3128
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff44ad31a3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
12  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x00007fff43dbbd96 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
13  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x00007fff43dbbb06 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
14  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x00007fff43dbb884 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
15  com.apple.AppKit              0x00007fff4206ea73 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
16  com.apple.AppKit              0x00007fff42804e34 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
17  com.apple.AppKit              0x00007fff42063885 -[NSApplication run] + 764
18  com.apple.AppKit              0x00007fff42032a72 NSApplicationMain + 804
19  libdyld.dylib                 0x00007fff6cde9015 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: PAPreviewWriter Render Queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00007fff6cf3b0ba pread + 10
1   com.apple.ImageIO.framework   0x00007fff47435425 IIOImageRead::getFileBytesAtOffset(void*, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 329
2   com.apple.ImageIO.framework   0x00007fff47434dae IIOImageRead::getBytesAtOffset(void*, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 392
3   com.apple.ImageIO.framework   0x00007fff473a39b7 IIOImageSource::doBindToReader() + 245
4   com.apple.ImageIO.framework   0x00007fff473a3c2c IIOImageSource::getType() + 14
5   com.apple.ImageIO.framework   0x00007fff4737d18c CGImageSourceGetType + 131
6   com.apple.photo.PAImagingCore 0x00007fff6300ad7e -[PAImageLoader _addOptionsForImageSource:sizePolicy:orientation:createThumbnail:] + 90
7   com.apple.photo.PAImagingCore 0x00007fff6300d2aa -[PAImageLoader _newCGImageForRequest:error:createThumbnail:applyTransform:orientation:] + 325
8   com.apple.photo.PAImagingCore 0x00007fff6300d0fe -[PAImageLoader _newCGImageForRequest:orientation:error:] + 106
9   com.apple.photo.PAImagingCore 0x00007fff63010f20 -[PAImageLoader newCGImageForRequest:error:] + 93
10  com.apple.photo.PAImagingCore 0x00007fff63010cb0 -[PAImageLoader bufferForRequest:canceler:error:] + 220
11  com.apple.photo.PAImaging     0x00007fff62df2c81 -[PAImageRequestService submitDirectPreviewRequest:canceler:] + 9140
12  com.apple.photo.PAImagingCore 0x00007fff63010b37 -[PADirectPreviewRequest submitSynchronous:] + 80
13  com.apple.photo.PAImaging     0x00007fff62ee50ae -[PAPreviewWriter _unprocessedImageForVersion:imageStyle:outMakerNote:] + 932
14  com.apple.photo.PAImaging     0x00007fff62ee111f -[PAPreviewWriter _inputImageForPreviews:imageProxyState:renderDescription:editStatus:force:outpu tImageStyle:canceler:previewMaker:] + 1537
15  com.apple.photo.PAImaging     0x00007fff62ee41b8 -[PAPreviewWriter _renderPreviewForImageVersion:imageProxyState:force:priority:canceler:] + 1426
16  com.apple.photo.PAImaging     0x00007fff62ee88c0 __70-[PAPreviewWriter renderThumbnailsForVersion:force:canceler:priority:]_block_invoke + 4353
17  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff6cdc5e5e _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 102
18  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff6cdafe08 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
19  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff6cdc4267 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 635
20  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff6cdb71b6 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 373
21  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff6cdc4f5d _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 332
22  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff6cdc8d71 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 880
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff6d100fd2 _pthread_wqthread + 980
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff6d100be9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00007fff6cf3020a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00007fff6cf2f724 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff44ad47d5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff44ad3b27 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation      0x00007fff44ad31a3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5   com.apple.AppKit              0x00007fff421abfc4 _NSEventThread + 184
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff6d101661 _pthread_body + 340
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff6d10150d _pthread_start + 377
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff6d100bf9 thread_start + 13
```

Comment: Hi there, anybody able to help me with this. It is 4 months since I first asked this and the problem still exists.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same behaviour on a single person's people/faces in my library.

Comment: I've been researching this on the internet and lots of people have this problem but it seems there is no solution, so I've just set up a smart album and will have to live with it. I am thinking of creating a new photos library and see if that helps. Let me know if you do find a way of fixing this! Cheers!